# Insert and update in same query or trigger suggestion

Tags: sql, triggers, postgresql-9.5

I'm wondering if this is the correct approach to have insert and update in this way, I think disadvantage is that payout_date in update won't be exactly the same as insert to transactions table, in the big datasets it might be te problem...

This function simply puts qualifying payouts to transactions table, where they are further processed by java application. And I want to simultaneously put payout_date in payouts table, which indicates it has been already moved.

Or should I use trigger? But I don't know how to construct it for this case.

Here's the sample dataset and code:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kNn3c3F96nqEwHoq9biF81/1

```
create table payouts 
(payout_id integer,
 customer_id integer,
 update_time timestamptz,
 amount integer,
 is_blocked boolean,
 payout_date timestamptz,
 paid_by integer);

 create table users
 (customer_id integer,
  account_number integer);

  create table transactions
  (transaction_id serial, 
   transaction_type integer,
   transaction_date timestamptz,
   account_number integer,
   reference_id integer,
   amount integer, 
   external_id integer);

    insert into payouts (payout_id, customer_id, update_time, amount, is_blocked)
    values 
    (1,1000, now() - interval '5 hours', 323, FALSE),
     (2,1005, now() - interval '5 hours', 66, FALSE),
      (3,1077, now() - interval '5 hours', -200, FALSE),
       (4,1077, now() - interval '5 hours', 88, TRUE),
        (5,2112, now() - interval '5 hours', 153, FALSE);

       insert into users
       values
       (1000, 2000),
        (1005, 2005),
         (1077,2077),
          (2112,3112),
           (1033,2033);




INSERT INTO transactions
( transaction_type
, transaction_date
, account_number
, reference_id
, amount)

SELECT
    100
  , now()
  , u.account_number
  , p.payout_id
  , p.amount 
  FROM
  payouts p
  JOIN users u ON u.customer_id = p.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.reference_id = p.payout_id and t.account_number = u.account_number and t.transaction_type = 100 
  WHERE payout_date is null and p.amount > 0  and is_blocked is FALSE
  AND t.account_number is null 
  AND t.reference_id is null;

  UPDATE payouts p 
  set
    payout_date = now()
  , paid_by = 111 -- variable in function

  FROM  payouts p2 
  JOIN users u ON u.customer_id = p2.customer_id
  LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.reference_id = p2.payout_id and t.account_number = u.account_number and t.transaction_type = 100
  WHERE p.payout_id = p2.payout_id  
  AND p2.payout_date is null and p2.amount > 0  and p2.is_blocked is FALSE
  AND t.account_number is NOT null 
  AND t.reference_id is NOT null;
```

Comment: `AND t.account_number is NOT null` will reduce your LEFT JOIN to a plain JOIN.

Comment: Yeah, good observation, I literally copied clauses from insert and just added NOT thoughtlessly. But that's the smallest issue there :) I already realized that triggers are rather a must have in such situations but its synthax is not so easy and I find it difficult to achieve my objective there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to create insert and update in one batch, using `returning`

with data_selected as
    (SELECT
        100
      , now()
      , u.account_number
      , p.payout_id
      , p.amount 
      FROM
      payouts p
      JOIN users u ON u.customer_id = p.customer_id
      LEFT JOIN transactions t ON t.reference_id = p.payout_id and t.account_number = u.account_number and t.transaction_type = 100 
      WHERE payout_date is null and p.amount > 0  and is_blocked is FALSE
      AND t.account_number is null 
      AND t.reference_id is null;
    ),

```
insert_data as (

INSERT INTO transactions
( transaction_type
, transaction_date
, account_number
, reference_id
, amount)

returning reference_id)


update payouts p
set
    payout_date = now()
  , paid_by = adminId

FROM insert_data id

where p.payout_id =  id.reference_id;
```